# Stopping or cancelling queued keyboard commands in a program

Tags: python-2.7, command, disabled-input

I have a program written in python 2.7 which takes photos of a sample from 3 different cameras when the result value is typed into the program.

The USB controller bandwidth can't handle all cameras firing at the same time, so I have to call each one individually. This causes a delay between pressing the value and the preview of the pictures showing up.

During this delay, the program is still able to accept keyboard commands which are then addressed once the photos have been taken. This is causing issues, as sometimes, values are inputted twice, which means that the value is then applied to the next one after it has taken the photos for the first sample.

What I'm after is a **way to disregard any queued keyboard commands** whilst the program is working on the current command:

```
def selChange(self):
    #Disable the textbox
    self.valInput.configure(state='disabled')

    #Gather pictures from cameras and store them in 2D list with sample result (This  takes a second or two to complete)
    self.gatherPictures()

    if not int(self.SampleList.size()) == 0:
        #clear texbox
        self.valInput.delete(0,END)

        #Create previews from 2D list
        self.img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.dataList[int(self.SampleList.curselection()[0])][2].resize((250,250),Image.ANTIALIAS))
        self.pic1.configure(image = self.img1)
        self.img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.dataList[int(self.SampleList.curselection()[0])][3].resize((250,250),Image.ANTIALIAS))
        self.pic2.configure(image = self.img2)
        self.img3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.dataList[int(self.SampleList.curselection()[0])][4].resize((250,250),Image.ANTIALIAS))
        self.pic3.configure(image = self.img3)
        self.img4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Data/" + str(self.dataList[int(self.SampleList.curselection()[0])][1]) + ".jpg").resize((250,250),Image.ANTIALIAS))
        self.pic4.configure(image = self.img4)

    #Unlock textbox ready for next sample
    self.valInput.configure(state='normal')
```

I was hoping that disabling the textbox and re-enabling it afterwards would work, but it doesn't. I wanted to use buttons, but they have insisted that it be typed to increase speed

Comment: I would disable the input until the last command is already done. But that depends on how is written how to add commands to the program. Are  you using tkinter or a similar package to make it easier for them?

Comment: I'm using Tkinter yea.  The first command issued is to disable the textbox and the last one is enable it again.  It's still queuing up the keyboard input for after the commands have all finished so the disabling during running has no effect at all.

Comment: When /how is this method called?

Comment: self.valInput.configure(state='disabled')
at the start and then state='normal' at the end

Comment: I mean the method  self.selChange. Do  you really use it to enter the information of which images to use?

Comment: @Llopis Oh right, sorry.  What I've got on my ui is a listbox, a text box, 3 picture boxes and a number of buttons. The list box contains a list of all the sample numbers which need pictures taking of and the results entering. The users need to have the program set up so that you only have to put in the value to apply it. This means that I have to have the code trigger on the textbox value changing. The method I posted is triggered after the value has been checked by a previous method to make sure it's a legitimate result.

Comment: If I understood correctly the user writes in the textbox which sample of the listbox will use the 3 pictures. Does he need to press enter or ok or something similar?. Why don't you disable while checking the input and able it again after the result is generated.

Comment: @Llopis It's all part of the same thread so the keyboard input is still queued up till after the code has finished. Unfortunately, this would mean that the input box is enabled just before the keyboard input is processed.  I guess I could try using a different thread to handle enabling and disabling of the input box.  Just seems like there should be an easier way of doing it.

Comment: This program is multi threading? The question seems too open to have an answer unless you provide more information. Would you mind editing the question with the information on the comments and more information about the class methods and widgets involved in the operation?